# how to fix Scrapy in depth crawling not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm currently trying to create a small web scraping prototype using scrapy.
My current issue is related to link extraction and following.

I'm trying to make scrapy explore pages and find links to pages (not images and other content for now) but I don't know how to parameter it correctly.

This is the spider I'm using :

```
class DefaultSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "default"
    session_id = -1
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()),callback='parse', follow=True)]
        
def start_requests(self):
     #not relevent code that gives an URL list to be scrawled
     for url in listurl:

     #make scrapy follow only the current domain url.
     self.rules[0].allow=url
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
     page = Website(response.url,response.text)
     DBInterface.store(page)
```

The spider doesnt seem to find any links in the pages. I think I'm not doing it the proper way. I tried to another function as a callback instead of the parse method. (changing the rule callback parameter too)

```
def processlinks (self,response)
    page = Website(response.url,response.text)
    DBInterface.store(page)
```

edit: update code + title for proper understanding..

Answer (score 0):

`CrawlSpider` is a special kind of spider that adds `rules` support to follow links (not extract them btw).

For this spider to work, you [can't override](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) the `start_requests` and `parse` methods

About getting links, I would recommend using the `LinkExtractor` which makes the extraction cleaner:

from scrapy

```
def find_links(self, response):
    for link in LinkExtractor().extract_links(response):
        logging.info('Extracting new url' + link.url)
        yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.insert_linkDB)
```

More and updated information for `LinkExtractor` is available [in the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html)

Comment: I understood your proposition, but I think you misunderstood what I meant, I properly edited the title and my code in order to make it more clear. I would like to do an indepth Thanks !

Comment: maybe you didn't read the first part of my answer, but when using `CrawlSpider`, you can't override `start_requests` and `parse` methods. I keep seeing those in your code, so that could be the reason why your spider is not working.

Comment: " I tried to another function as a callback instead of the parse method. (changing the rule callback parameter too)" I quote. It acts the same way if i override the parse or use another method as a callback.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat tricky to make `CrawlSpider` handle initial URLs same way as those that it subsequently extracts with `LinkExtractor`, which is what you want here. The problem is that you **should not** define custom callback for any requests that you manually initiate, as it would prevent `LinkExtractor` from working. On the other hand, you want to perform some action for each crawled URL, including the initial URLs. For those URLs extracted with `LinkExtractor`, you can provide the callback when defining the rule, but that obviously wouldn't work for initial URLs which are not extracted using these rules. For this purpose, Scrapy provides another method [`parse_start_url(response)`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) which you can, and should override. So in your case, the following would do what you want:

```
class DefaultSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "default"
    session_id = -1
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()),callback='parse_results', follow=True)]

def start_requests(self):
     #not relevent code that gives an URL list to be scrawled
     for url in listurl:

     #make scrappy follow only the current domain url.
     self.rules[0].allow=url
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url)

def parse_start_url(self, response):
     self.parse_results(response)

def parse_results(self, response):
     page = Website(response.url,response.text)
     DBInterface.store(page)
```